# Using Accessorizer doesn't paste generated code

Tags: xcode, accessorizer

I'm trying to get into Accessorizer, but every time I am trying it, I run into the same problem. I select some code (for example, multiple @property statements), hit cmd-c and move my cursor to the place I want the generated code to be.

I now use Accessorizer's menu, select Implementation and my copied properties are pasted in, instead of @synthesize statements. As far as I can see, I followed the setup instructions precisely. I don't like the difficult to use shortcuts, so I would like to use the system menu, at least for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, so you need to invoke the Accessorizer text service by pressing shift-alt-cmd-0 instead of cmd-c. That sends the text to Accessorizer. Only after you've done this, you can use the Action Menu / press shift-ctrl-cmd-0.